# Android OpenCV: How to slow down camera capture frame rate (purposefully)

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, frame-rate

I'm currently developing an Android face detection app, and I'm wondering how I can slow down the capture frame rate purposefully. Currently it is around 30fps, and all I really require is 5-10fps. That way I don't need to use up additional processing which can be used on other tasks.

I'm wondering if a `Thread.sleep()` is all that is needed to do the trick, [or should I look into setting it via](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) `cvSetCaptureProperty(CvCapture* capture, int property_id, double value)`? I read that it only works on certain cameras though, and is, for the most part, useless...

I have also read about setting maximum frame size (e.g. `mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(640, 480);`) but... it doesn't make sense to me to do that?..

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
        int height = mGray.rows();
        if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
            mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
        }
        mNativeDetector.setMinFaceSize(mAbsoluteFaceSize);
    }

    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

    if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR) {
        if (mJavaDetector != null)
            mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, SCALE_FACTOR, MIN_NEIGHBOURS, 2, 
                    new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
    }
    else if (mDetectorType == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
        if (mNativeDetector != null)
            mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faces);
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
    }

    //put thread to sleep to slow capture?  
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mRgba;
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend to you to use `cvSetCaptureProperty()` because its behaviour is very rhapsodic.

You should rather register the timestamp of last frame arrived (and processed) to `onCameraFrame()` and return from the event handler if the difference between last timestamp and now is less then ~100 ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter. Let's say fps=30, and you want to process only 5fs, then we have:

```
class YourClass{
   int counter = 0;
   // Your code
   public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
      counter++;
      if (counter < 6)
          return null;
      counter = 0;
      //Your processing code here
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running:

SystemClock.sleep(...);

in onCameraFrame works well for me and reduces power usage of the app.